# Cannot publish individual customization packages in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I'm having a strange problem on my development workstation. I can no longer publish **ANY single**  customization package within Acumatica using the Project Browser window. But strangely, I can still publish **ALL packages** without issue from the main Customization Project screen (SM204505). This makes for an awkward development workflow.

This behavior started after I upgraded Visual Studio between minor versions: 15.9.17 to 15.9.28.

Here's a screenshot of the error in the Project Browser:

[image]

The 505 error trace log in Event Viewer:

```
Exception information:
    Exception type: NullReferenceException
    Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at PX.Customization.CstValidationProcess.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in C:\Bld2\AC-FULL2019R113-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Web.Customization\Publish\CstValidationProcess.cs:line 89
   at ASP.controls_publish_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\AcumaticaSites\TemporaryAspFiles\2019r1\2019r1\e88eaed9\5694cb3e\App_Web_publish.aspx.cc671b29.dndzcldh.0.cs:line 0
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Request information:
    Request URL: http://localhost/2019r1/Controls/Publish.aspx?compile=true&callback_id=0&suffix=40060f45-d71e-4139-9922-bb678ddbdfb1
    Request path: /2019r1/Controls/Publish.aspx
    User host address: ::1
    User: admin
    Is authenticated: True
    Authentication Type: Forms
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool
```

I'm not sure what to try to resolve this. Any ideas?

Comment: I've opened a ticket with Acumatica and they have acknowledged it's a known issue. Once I hear back from them, I will try to contact you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the email I got from Acumatica Support:

We've investigated the issue and found that it is caused by compatibility with new version of .Net Framework.

You can find more details here:

https://community.acumatica.com/customization-and-development-72/known-issue-after-an-upgrade-to-net-framework-version-4-8-4250-users-were-unable-to-publish-a-customization-project-from-the-customization-project-editor-3854

This issue is fixed in the following versions:

- 2019 R1 Update 22
- 2019 R2 Update 15
- 2020 R1 Update 13
- 2020 R2 Update 3

As a workaround you can set the following flag to false in the web.config of the site (appSettings section): `<add key="aspnet:DisableAppPathModifier" value="false" />`

Full Credit: Dmitry Naumov

Comment: It should also possible to publish from the Customization screen instead of within the customization itself.